# how to change the content of a panel using another panel from another classe in java

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

On Eclipse, using JFrames, I'm using a mainFrame as the main user interface and in that frame i got a contentPanel (JPanel) containing a small panel (JPanel as well), under that panel there's a buttong, and i have another class which i named 'clients' (another frame) containting a contentPanel too (JPanel) with other compenents, i want to get the the second class contentPanel to show in the first's panel (the small panel i mentionned).
here's what i did, but it's not working!! any help?

*MainF.java*

```
public class mainF extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane;
    public JPanel panel;
    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    mainF frame = new mainF();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public mainF() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 450, 404);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(null);

        panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBounds(10, 11, 414, 256);
        contentPane.add(panel);
        panel.setLayout(null);

        JLabel Panel = new JLabel("Main Panel");
        Panel.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        Panel.setBounds(10, 11, 69, 33);
        panel.add(Panel);


        JButton btnClients = new JButton("Clients");
        btnClients.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                panel = new Clients().getContentPane();
                panel.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
        btnClients.setBounds(162, 296, 89, 23);
        contentPane.add(btnClients);
    }

}
```

**Clients**

```
public class Clients extends JFrame {
private JPanel contentPane;

public JPanel getContentPane() {
    return contentPane;
}

public Clients() {
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    setContentPane(contentPane);
    contentPane.setLayout(null);

    JLabel lblClients = new JLabel("Clients");
    lblClients.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    lblClients.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.BOLD, 18));
    lblClients.setBounds(10, 11, 85, 37);
    contentPane.add(lblClients);
}
}
```

Thanks Everyone!!

here's an image to explain the situation:

[image]

Comment: what exactly is not working?

Comment: as u can see, in the main class, i created a new JPanel instantiating  the JPanel of the Clients class, the problem is that the new JPanel is not getting the other class's JPanel's components

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[See the image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1zbmp.png) 
You are using one JPanel reference `panel`, and using it to create 2 different panel objects. So first remove the `panel` from `contentPane` then add it back with new initialization.

```
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
     contentPane.remove(panel);
     panel = new Clients().getContentPane();
     panel.setVisible(true);
     contentPane.add(panel);
     contentPane.repaint();
     contentPane.revalidate();

     }
   });
```

Also you require `contentpane` to `revalidate()` and `repaint()`